# How do I empty a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

How in SQLite do I EMPTY a table?

If I execute "DELETE * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID > 0" the IDs won't start at 1 the next time I enter a record.

Comment: By the way, what is the point of adding the condition? If you want the table empty, why not just `DELETE * FROM tablename` (without a `WHERE`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE  FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE  NAME =  'TABLENAME'`

Answer (score 1):

To truly wipe out all traces of the table, you have to drop it and then recreate it. If you're specifically worried about an `AUTOINCREMENT` column, you can manipulate [the `sqlite_sequence` table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab) to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM tablename;

DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='tablename';